# Движки форумов на php с xslt

Tags: форум, php, движок, xslt

Здравствуйте!
Меня не забанили в Google:), но либо я неправильные слова вбиваю в запрос, либо одно из двух. Тем не менее, я сам ответа на свой вопрос не нашел, и прошу помощи сообщества.

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие есть готовые движки форумов (желательно бесплатные), которые для отображения используют xslt-шаблоны. Ну или если по-другому, то движки, которые могут возвращать данные в xml.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторонону коммерческих
CMS, многие из них используют xslt. В hostcms например точно есть форум и точно используется xslt